# Compile program using a Makefile with gcc instead of clang

Tags: makefile

I am writing a program to spell-check a given text. On my pc I used this Makefile to compile the program:

```
# compiler to use
CC = clang

# flags to pass compiler
CFLAGS = -ggdb3 -O0 Qunused-arguments -std=c99 -Wall -Werror

# name for executable
EXE = speller

# space-separated list of header files
HDRS = dictionary.h

# space-separated list of source files
SRCS = speller.c dictionary.c

# automatically generated list of object files
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

# default target
$(EXE): $(OBJS) $(HDRS) Makefile
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

# dependencies
$(OBJS): $(HDRS) Makefile
```

I would like to continue programming on my Raspberry Pi but I only have gcc installed. Is it possible to make this Makefile work for gcc? I tried to change the compiler with:

```
CC = gcc
```

but It doesn't work. I get the error message "unrecognised option -Qunused-arguments".

Comment: You adjusted `CC` to your desired compiler now you need to adjust your compiler flags to account for the fact that you are using a different compiler. Is the question what the equivalent arguments are? Is the question how to handle this in an automated fashion in the makefile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `-Q` option which Clang accepts isn't an option which GCC recognises.

GCC and Clang are completely separate compilers, and so one shouldn't really expect one of them to understand the other's options.  In fact, Clang does make some efforts to be modestly compatible with GCC, in large part to make it possible to use it as a drop-in replacement for GCC.  However that compatibility isn't, and probably shouldn't be, complete.

So your solution is simply to change the `CFLAGS` definition at the same time as you change the `CC` definition.