# MAKE on new iMAC with CLANG, but Makefile refers to GCC

Tags: gcc, compilation, makefile, clang

I seek some help with 2 Makefiles for 2 different software that are much older than my iMAC machine. I think the software assumes the C compiler to be GCC, while my new iMAC has CLANG as default I think...

I know there are some other threads on this general topic such as at : [Compile program using a Makefile with gcc instead of clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367718/compile-program-using-a-makefile-with-gcc-instead-of-clang)

But I wonder if there are Makefile specific modifications for these 2 software that you can suggest I perform. I dont have any experience with modifying Makefiles or flags etc.

The 2 Makefiles and the software that they come from can be all accessed from the folder at [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/afca00uw330k2dl/AABzO7vBEgM0i-GcFqVJ-kD4a?dl=0).  Thank you!

My **make** attempt for **mdust** looks like this:

1. Checked http://b110-wiki.dkfz.de/confluence/display/nextrnai/Step-by-step+installation+on+MAC for details on

   Installation of mdust

   Mdust can be downloaded via this link.

   Unpack the file. In the folder created open fastafile.c and delete the third line #include  (malloc.h is not needed under Mac OS X, but leads to an error with make). Finally typemake (ignore warnings) which creates the mdust script required by NEXT-RNAi (compilation requires prior installation of Apple Developer Tools / Xcode).

   ```
   tar -xvzf mdust.tar.gz
   cd mdust
   emacs fastafile.c (delete line include )
   make
   ```
2. So I opened fastafile.c with vi and deleted the 
   line include
3. But now, when I try make, I think I see CLANG Vs gcc compiler issues.

   ```
   DCook04-2:mdust anand$ make
   gcc -O2 -Wall -I. -I-  -D_REENTRANT -c fastafile.c -o fastafile.o
   clang: error: '-I-' not supported, please use -iquote instead
   make: *** [fastafile.o] Error 1
   ```

My **make** attempt for **RECON** may have worked, only warning, no errors per STDOUT. Longer STDOUT, so in folder with link above, and obviously named file.

More info that's hopefully relevant:

```
DCook04-2:src anand$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

```
DCook04-2:src anand$ clang -v
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: The error `clang: error: '-I-' not supported, please use -iquote instead` seems pretty clear. You need to find where (in the makefiles) that `-I-` flag is used and replace it with `-iquote` it would seem.

Comment: Thank you @EtanReisner. Still getting warnings and error despite your suggested mod. New MakeFile and STDOUT of new make attempt at same link in original posting. Could you please suggest additional mods? Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting similar errors that tell you what to do?

Comment: So that's a "yes". The warnings tell you what to do to fix the problem. The error tells you that you have object files that aren't correctly built for your target platform. Rebuild them.